# Python + Arduino with Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, serial-port, arduino

I'm having trouble communicating between my Arduino and Python. I have a couple of questions that I hope can be answered, but first and most importantly, I need to simply establish a connection.

For Windows, apparently the solution is rather convenient, but on Mac OS X, I apparently need to access some system files (which I am not familiar with). The Python documentation points me to the specific post *[Re: Can Python do serial port stuff?](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/b200a1240617ca3a)*, but I don't think it quite serves my purposes.

At this point, trying to merely see evidence of communication I've tried this.

Arduino:

```
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int d = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(d,BYTE);
}
```

Python: (pretty much from the mentioned link...)

```
 #!usr/bin/python
 import os, fcntl, termios, sys

 serialPath = '/dev/tty.usbmodemfa141'

 ser= os.open(serialPath, 0)
 [iflag, oflag, cflag, lflag, ispeed, ospeed, cc] = range(7)
 settings = termios.tcgetattr(ser)
 settings[ospeed] = termios.B9600
 settings[ispeed] = termios.B0
 print 2
```

As evidenced here, I really don't understand what the modules I am importing are doing exactly. While reading the documentation I see no obvious way to send data over serial. So am I right in guessing that whatever the output of this program is it will be sent over automatically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to communicate in Python with the Arduino (or any microcontroller with serial) is using [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/).

Here's an example:

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.usbmodemfa141', baudrate=9600)

s.write('text')
s.read()
s.readline()
```

PS: If you're using Python 3, you should send bytes instead of strings (that is, `b'text'`).

Comment: this is by far the easiest, +1

Comment: I was under the impression that pyserial won't work on osx... Am i mistaken?

Comment: It works on OSX. I only had problems with pyserial under Windows 64-bit

Comment: Oh, alright. Heh. I've just installed it and seems to be working fine... What is this about then? Just out of curiosity... http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#how-do-i-access-the-serial-rs232-port I was initially going to use pyserial, but I thought that this was saying it wouldn't work for osx.... D:

Comment: I don't know, but OSX is a BSD based system, so you don't have to worry about the second url.

Comment: It doesn't like me on OSX: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'. With a bit more investigation it turned out that I have serial already in my namespace from something else.

Answer (score 2):

On my side I've solved Serial error on OSX using the sudo command; I think that on OSX you have to get admin rights to communicate throw /dev/cu.usbmodem14101 with Serial after a pip install.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using Perl under Linux, but have no experience with Python or Mac. I can give you a few pointers to look for.

First, in your Python program you need to put the proper device address for your USB port in `serialPath` as otherwise your data will not reach the Arduino. In Linux I did a lsusb after I connected the board and found the device name from that.

In your Arduino code change it to be

```
void loop()
{
   if(Serial.available() > 0)
   {
       d = Serial.read();
       Serial.println(d,BYTE);
   }
}
```

as otherwise you will be dumping a bunch of -1s if there is no data.